# How to get model updated onkeyup in rivetjs

Tags: javascript, data-binding, rivets.js

First of all thanks for RivetJS, I'm using it for flow, is awesome!

Question: In AngularJS is usual to get the a binding in an input to update the model `onkeyup`. In RivetJS the default seems to be updating the model `onblur`. Is there a way to get it updating the model with each `onkeyup` event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options. Firstly, upgrade to Rivets 0.7 - as described in [the changelog](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), "The built-in value binder now listens on the input event instead of change, so updates will propogate immediately instead of on blur." Be aware of the breaking changes and upgrade your implementation accordingly (e.g. you either need to include [Sightglass](https://github.com/mikeric/sightglass) before Rivets or use [the bundled rivets.js file](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/blob/master/dist/rivets.bundled.min.js).

The other option, if you want to stay with Rivets 0.6, is to create your own binder. As the author himself [gives an example](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/issues/24#issuecomment-18516830) I would just use that:

```
rivets.binders.input = {
  publishes: true,
  routine: rivets.binders.value.routine,
  bind: function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('input', this.publish)
  },
  unbind: function(el) {
    el.removeEventListener('input', this.publish)
  }
}
```